# regex группа не работает

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения, reactjs, angular2

Так работает

```js
\??&{0,2}?lang=\w+?&{0,2}$|lang=\w+&{0,2}
```

Так нет.

```js
\??&{0,2}?(lang=)\w+?&{0,2}$|\1\w+&{0,2}
```

Comment: Хорошо...............

Comment: `console.log( /a(lang=)|b\1/.test('blang=') ); // true` — а у меня работает... Может что-то с вашей сторокой или другими частями регулярки. `&{0,2}` не забыли `w+` ? А `\w+&{0,2}` не должно быть в скобках? `(?:\w+&){0,2}` иначе `{0,2}` относится только к `&`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Работает, но немного не так, как можно ожидать) `'blang='.match(/a(lang=)|b\1/)` выдаст `[ 'b', undefined, index: 0, input: 'blang=', groups: undefined ]`. При этом `/a(lang=)|b\1/.test('b')` тоже выдаст `true`)

Comment: Обратная ссылка не ищет тот же шаблон, что в соответствующей подмаске. Это может сделать рекурсивный шаблон типа `(?1)` или  `\g<1>`, но в регулярных выражениях JavaScript они не поддерживаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете скобки и обратную ссылку по разные стороны знака альтернативного выбора, всё начинает работать не совсем очевидным образом.

Даже если в первой части альтернативы находится соответствие, вторая часть как бы забывает соответствие и его часть в скобках, так что обратная ссылка будет ссылаться на пустую строку и не будет включать ожидаемую часть, даже если она есть (и будет срабатывать, даже если её нет).

```js
> 'abca'.match(/(a)b|c\1/g)
[ 'ab', 'c' ]
> 'abc'.match(/(a)b|c\1/g)
[ 'ab', 'c' ]
```

Если первая часть альтернативы не найдена, происходит то же самое: обратная ссылка ссылается на пустую строку и всегда будет срабатывать независимо от того, что идёт на месте ожидаемой части (и есть ли там вообще что-то:

```js
> 'abcb'.match(/(a)a|c\1/g)
[ 'c' ]
> 'abc'.match(/(a)a|c\1/g)
[ 'c' ]
```